# Does SNMP version 1 and 2 Support TLS?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I'm trying to send a message via SNMP version 1 or 2.
I need TLS support for safe transmission.

Does both version support TLS?  (I'm using SNMP4j Library in Java)

Comment: No. Security related extensions are considered SNMP v3 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SNMP v1 and v2 send everything in plaintext over the network.
You have to use SNMP v3 together with the security level `authPriv`.

**Note:** SNMP v3 also support the security levels `noAuthNoPriv` and `authNoPriv` which will send the data unencrypted, too.